Our custom LWC that has config properties and is using Chart.js is silently failing in Summer '24
Working before Summer '24.
Now the component does not render and we see no errors in the console.
The component is used in a Digital Experience and is now not offered in the builder component list. In the builder for an existing site viewing the page results in:

We couldn't load that component

presented in red text in place of the component.
Anyone have any insight into the problem or suggestions on how to debug further?

What's your js-meta.xml file look like? Have you tried debugging with exception breakpoints? (F12 > Source > Break on caught exceptions/Break on uncaught exceptions, then step through the errors). There are a few expected errors because of browser feature detection, but after that, you should get into the code that's having a problem.

Thanks @sfdcfox. My colleague is looking at this and has identified a config property <property name="recordId" label="Record Id" description="" type="Id"/> as the likely cause. The docs don't include Id as a type; perhaps Summer '24 is more picky about this. Will post as the answer if conformed.

I concur with our colleague's suggestion. It most likely the cause, because you can only use the types in the documentation, and Id isn't one of them.

Turned out to be nothing to do with Chart.js but rather an LWC property definition of:
<property name="recordId" label="Record Id" description="" type="Id"/>

that didn't fail before Summer '24 but fails in Summer '24. So looks like Summer '24 is being more picky. The Id type is not included in the small list of type options in the documentation; this should be type="String".
As this LWC is in a managed package and there are live Digital Experiences using it, some manual intervention on the live Digital Experiences will be needed.
